# How to get input value (without ID) from table

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an input tag on table : 
example :

```
<table border="1" id="datatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="a[]" value="a1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="b[]" value="b1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="b[]" value="c1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="a[]" value="a2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="b[]" value="b2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="c[]" value="c2">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to get value from input using javascript.
I have try :

```
var x = document.getElementById("datatable").rows[1].cells;
alert(x[1].innerHTML);
```

but the result is :

```
<input type='text' value="a">
```

please help. thank you

Comment: Well you're not far off - x[1] is the table *cell*, i.e., the TD element. The input is the first child of that, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var x = document.getElementById("datatable").rows[1].cells;
alert(x[0].children[0].value);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid html. Each input element should have a name attribute this is how the forms data is submitted. Then you could use `value=document.querySelector("input[name='fred']").value;`

Edit
Since you are using brackets (and therefore sending back array value with same name) you will need to use:

```
// create array for values
a_s_array = [];
// get input values
a_s = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='a[]']");
// loop through elements
for( var x=0; x<a_s.length; x++ ) {
// store input value into array
   a_s_array.push( a_s[x].value );
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot place name attribute on example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jquery code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<table border="1" id="datatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="a[]" value="a1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="b[]" value="b1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="b[]" value="c1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="a[]" value="a2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="b[]" value="b2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name="c[]" value="c2">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var td = $("#datatable").find('td');
        $.each(td, function() { 
            alert($(this).find('input[type="text"]').val()); 
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```